# How can I download a PDF document that is embedded on a webpage in iOS?

Tags: ios, safari, pdf

If I'm viewing a webpage which embeds a PDF document with the `<object>` tag ([example](http://joliclic.free.fr/html/object-tag/en/object-application.html#pdf)), how can I download this page on the iPhone?

If I view a non-embedded PDF document ([example](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iphone_4s_important_product_information_guide.pdf)), I can select the `Open in...` option and download it to an application such as Dropbox. I have not found a way to do this when the PDF is embedded.

If there was a way to figure out the PDF's address, I could copy and paste it into the address bar, but I haven't figured out a way to do this either.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any way to do this in Safari?
2. Is there any way to get the URL of the embedded PDF document?
3. Are there any 3rd party applications for iOS that allow me to download, or get the address of, the embedded document?

Comment: Are PDFs embedded into web pages really that common?

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Chrome.  Chrome will have the disk save option icon at the bottom.  Chrome Web browser also has built-in print to PDF file.

Comment: If you can print, then you can print to PDF by default in OS X, it's not a Chrome thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could install a [View Source on iPhone](http://fettig.net/weblog/2007/07/02/view-source-for-safari-on-iphone/) bookmarklet and access the page content (including the link to the embedded pdf) directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. it works, but it gets difficult when the page has a lot of content. I'm hoping someone finds another solution which makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5.1.1 if found no way to get the PDF out of Safari without extra tools.

You can select the object (by double tap on it and hold) and select "copy", but i found no way to get anything out of it.

But with another webbrowser like "Opera mini" which don't show the PDf inline, you can get the URL or open the PDF direct in iBooks.

Comment: Bingo! After copying the object like that—double-tap and hold—you can paste into the address bar to get the PDF's URL. Tap "Go", and you get the standalone PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Try an app called [Offline Reader.](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/offline-reader-!/id411217271?mt=8)

When I open PDFs in Safari and tap on them it gives me the option to download them or open in iBooks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Frederico! Can you please add a link to the software you mention? Thank you.

Comment: Added the link on the answer